# If I encrypt my home folder during installation, can I do another clean installation over the entire hard drive?

Tags: encryption, ecryptfs

1. Let's say I install Ubuntu 10.10 with an encrypted folder or hard drive, and I plan on doing a clean install of Ubuntu 11.04. Will the encryption cause an issue? Or will it still be as simple as popping in the cd and clicking button?
2. Does encryption cause noticeable performance issues?
3. Would I be able to copy some files onto an external hard drive if they are encrypted? Or will I have to decrypt them before copying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Encryption won't interfere with your next installation at all.
2. I've used full disk and home folder encryption for several years now, but I've never noticed any difference in performance. The most significant bottleneck in retrieving encrypted data involves getting the bits off of your disk. By comparison, decryption is so fast it's almost always unnoticeable.
3. After logging in (or entering your password) you can backup or copy files from your encrypted drive/folder exactly as you normally would, without any extra considerations.

Full-disk and home folder encryption are transparent in most cases.

Answer (score 3):

1. You can either use the ecnrypted
   hard drive and install into it, or
   you could wipe the entire drive and
   install unencrypted. Both work fine.
2. For very disk I/O intensive stuff,
   you may be able to notice issues.
3. The general way this is done* is
   that when you grab them from the
   encrypted drive they are decrypted
   on the fly (I'm thinking TrueCrypt
   etc) so when you save them they will
   be unencrypted.

*some encryption tools are more strict and won't let this happen. Usually these are only used in restricted environments, or as part of data leakage/loss prevention